# How can I change the language in my Vue.js app using a query parameter, such as `?lang=en`?

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router, vite, pinia, vue-i18n

I'm working on a Vue.js app using Pinia for state management. I have a multilingual application with three languages (EN, RU, TJ), and I want to implement language switching using query parameters.

Here's a simplified version of my code:
this my main.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';
import { createI18n } from 'vue-i18n';
import { createPinia } from 'pinia';
import { productsStore } from './stores/products';
import EN from '../src/locale/en.json';
import RU from '../src/locale/ru.json';
import TJ from '../src/locale/tj.json';

const pinia = createPinia();
const app = createApp(App);

app.use(router);
app.use(pinia);

const store = productsStore();

const i18n = createI18n({
  legacy: false,
  locale: store.locale,
  messages: {
    EN: EN,
    RU: RU,
    TJ: TJ
  }
});

app.use(i18n);
app.mount('#app');
```

this is store.js

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";

export const productsStore = defineStore('products', {
    state: () => ({
        locale: 'TJ',
    }),
})
```

router.js

```
import {
    createRouter,
    // createWebHashHistory
    createWebHistory
} from "vue-router";
import Birthday from '../views/Birthday.vue'
import Gifts from '../views/Gifts.vue'
import Discounts from '../views/Discounts.vue'
import Mbback from '../views/Mb_back.vue'

const routes = [{
        path: '/',
        name: 'birthday',
        component: Birthday
    },
    {
        path: '/gifts',
        name: 'gifts',
        component: Gifts
    },
    {
        path: '/discounts',
        name: 'discounts',
        component: Discounts
    },
    {
        path: '/mb_back',
        name: 'mb_back',
        component: Mbback,
    },
]

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes
})

export default router
```

I have tried to set the locale in my Pinia store based on the query parameter, but it doesn't seem to work as expected. I've also set up my routes, and I want the language to change when the user provides a **`lang`** query parameter in the URL.

What am I missing or doing wrong in my implementation? Any suggestions on how to properly implement language switching in a Vue.js app using Pinia and query parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const language = ref(route.query?.lang); // initialize variable with change tracking capabilities from home?lang=en

watchEffect(() => {
   language.value = route.query?.lang // update whenever the lang=en on address changes
   if (language.value === 'en') {
   }
   else if (language.value === 'fr') {
   }
}
```